# SQL - Find number of new starters and leavers between snapshot dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, difference

I have an SQL table `staff` that takes a snapshot on specific dates and adds a row of every `staffID` and the corresponding `DateID`.

I need to find out how many staff have joined since the next `DateID`, and how many have left.

So in the example `staff` table below at DateID B, `StaffID`'s `002` and `003` from `DateID` `A` aren't there so have 'left', and `DateID` `B` has `staffID`'s `004`,`005`,`006` that were not there in `DateID` so are 'new'.

```
StaffID  DateID
007      C
005      C
006      B
005      B
004      B
001      B
003      A
002      A
001      A
```

I've surmised how these results would appear in the below.

```
DateID  New  Leavers
A       0    2
B       3    2
C       1    3
```

My current and only way of solving this is to go through each `DateID` with the `DateID` before it and left join the older date counting the rows where the old date it null for the number of new staff and swapping the tables round for the leavers.

```
SELECT t1.DateID, count(*) AS Total

(SELECT *
FROM staff
WHERE DateID = 'B') t1

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT *
FROM staff
WHERE DateID = 'A') t2

ON t1.StaffID = t2.StaffID
WHERE t2.StaffID is null
GROUP BY t1.DateID
```

This method is horribly inefficient with a larger table and hoping anyone has ideas for a way to do in one script. Alternatively, a script just for new staff and a script for just leavers would be as good.

---

As requested by @Larnu, I've added a `snapshot` table that holds all the DateID's. the `staff` table is filtered to just show DateID's that are weekly.

```
DateID Weekly Monthly Yearly
A      Y      Y       N
B      Y      N       N
C      Y      N       N
D      N      N       N
E      Y      Y       N
F      N      N       Y
```

Comment: What "Date" is `'A'`? Is `'A'` before or after `'C'`? How do you know? What happens when you get to "date" `'Z'`, do you have date `'AA'`?

Comment: Yes 'A' would be the first date, then B, then C. This is dummy data so you can end at Z or continue with AA. There wouldn't really be an end date with this.

Comment: I would suggest using meaningful data, @WillacyMe . Using letters to define dates is *very* confusing. The order for such dates would be `ORDER BY LEN(DateId), DateID`, which is *not* intuitive...

Comment: Are dates (letters?) also consecutive as well? Could you be missing "date" `'D'` but have a "date" `'e'` for example?

Comment: The actual data uses a 4 digit number which increases in size with every snapshot. I used letters here so as to make it clearer differentiating between the datesID and staffIDs. Would changing it to AAAA, AAAB, AAAC or 0001, 0002 etc. make more sense?

Comment: Neither really make any sense, if I am honest; unless `DateID` is a foreign key to a table that contains the actual date?

Comment: @Larnu The date letters are consecutive but could be missing a letter so there could be A, then B, then D. In such case C would never appear after D as they would always be in order.

Comment: @Larnu,  Yes DateID is taken from a foreign key. DateID could have 4001, 4002, 4003 values but some of these ID's refer to weekly, yearly, or monthly snapshots. The above table `staff` is an example of a temp table where only the necessary snapshot dateIDs are listed. So it could be 4001, then 4005, but these numbers are always in order. There won't be a DateID that is 4004 after 4005.

Comment: That would be more meaningful, put both tables in the question, Your existing data with your foreign key, and then the table that is related to.

Comment: @Larnu added it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEAD` and `LAG` window functions would help here.

Since the `DateID`s are not consecutive, you need to calculate `LEAD/LAG` on that also, and join it

```sql
SELECT
  s.DateID,
  [New]   = COUNT(CASE WHEN s.PrevID IS NULL OR s.PrevID <> d.PrevDateID THEN 1 END),
  Leavers = COUNT(CASE WHEN s.NextID IS NULL OR s.NextID <> d.NextDateID THEN 1 END)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      PrevDateID =  LAG(DateID) OVER (ORDER BY DateID),
      NextDateID = LEAD(DateID) OVER (ORDER BY DateID)
    FROM Dates d
) d
JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      PrevID =  LAG(s.DateID) OVER (PARTITION BY StaffID ORDER BY DateID),
      NextID = LEAD(s.DateID) OVER (PARTITION BY StaffID ORDER BY DateID)
    FROM staff s
) s ON s.DateID = d.DateID
GROUP BY
  s.DateID;
```

Comment: This is great thank you. I didn't know about the LEAD and LAG window functions.